# Setting up Spotify API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, spotify-app

I've been following the [Spotify quick start guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/) but am having issues around the "Add the App Remote SDK" section.

[When I try to import the module I get these options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDksw.png)
 But I don't see the "Import .JAR/AAR Package" button like they show. Instead I have been clicking on 'import' and then selecting the 'app-remote-lib' folder.

I've then placed this code in my app-level build.gradle dependencies section:

```
implementation project(':app-remote-lib')
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
```

However now when I add in my dependencies into the MainActivity I just get redtext to tell me it ["cannot resolve symbol 'spotify'"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv8X1.png)

Can anyone give me a hand here? I'm not sure how to get the spotify API working from this point.

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow steps

```
1. delete the module, .idea folder, and then run an Invalidate Caches/Restart;
2. before re-installing the module keep the implementation project(':spotify-app-remote') on your Gradle files;
3. right-click on the app folder and choose New-> Module;
4. choose import .jar/aar package (if you import the module via the file menu it will never work don't ask me why hahaha)
5. rename the module name to :spotify-app-remote and hit finish;
```

Answer (score 0):

click on file>new>import project>then open `spotify-app-remote-release-0.7.2.aar` file from `app-remote-lib` folder of sdk  that you downloaded[image]